# Web site with multiple languages can't use VB.NET classes in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm developing a new functionality for web site project with VB.NET default language in VS 2008. As my preferred language is C# I create subfolder for C# code in the `App_Code` folder and add appropriate `codeSubDirectories` element to web.config file. The problem is that I can't refer VB.NET classes in my C# code. All VB.NET classes and structures are placed in global namespace in the App_Code. But even if I place some VB.NET class in the same namespace I've use for my classes in C#, I still can't use them. Also, I've try to move my class to global namespace but this also doesn't help me.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation for [codeSubDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dwfbb7.aspx):

> The build order is inferred from the top-down order of the codeSubDirectories collection. The App_Code directory is built last.

Which implies that when your C# code is being compiled, the VB code hasn't been compiled at that point. You might try and separate base classes, etc, and put them in an earlier subdirectory or into a compiled class library, but I'd probably recommend just writing your code in VB - it's not *that* tricky to write in one when you're used to the other - the framework is still the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing order of `codeSubDirectories` nodes resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create two folders under App_Code folder named CSCode and VBCode. Move your respective files to respected folders

Add below code in web.config file:

```
  <codeSubDirectories>
    <add directoryName="CSCode"></add>
    <add directoryName="VBCode"/>

  </codeSubDirectories>
```

and then try...

-Rakesh