# Accessing VB Code in App_Code from C# Codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, app-code

I'm working on a web project (not web site) in VS that is mainly written in VB. I'm creating a new Web Form using C#. The web form in itself works great, but I'm not able to access classes in App_Code folder. The classes in the App_Code folder are written in VB.net.

I've tried to set Build Action on the vb class file to compile, but this only result in the file not building. (Getting errors on commented lines "Too many characters in character literal" and the imports "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"). I've also tried to "using" the App_Code folder but I'm not able to find it.

Any suggestions on how I may solve this, or work around would be greatly appreciated.

--- Edit ---

Visual Studio seems to behave differently if you open a web site as “Web Application” instead of “Web Site”. I guess this is because it’s packing the files or something. I’m sorry I weren’t aware of this, and this is what’s causing the problem. The web site is a CMS system written in VB, but I’m building custom User Controls/Web Forms in C# to it, this worked fine when I had it as Web Site, but not as Web Application. We’re trying to migrate this CMS system to Azure and I started with a fresh install of the CMS system. Only way to create a web role from the site is if it's a Web Application. This is why I didn’t spot this problem before now that I got the site up running on Azure and I started creating custom modules to the CMS.

--- Edit: The workaround ---

I started all over again with the CMS installation clean, out of the box and imported it into a Web Application Project. I then created two new libraries, a C# lib, and a VB lib. I moved the code in the App_Code folder to the VB lib, and made a refrence to this lib in both Web Application project and C# lib. I made a refrence to the C# lib in the Web Application project, and in the C# lib did I add in the build action to copy over .aspx and .ascx files to the Web Application projects representative folder. I can now create new Web Controls and Web Forms with C# as language.

Comment: Sounds like you've got other compile-time errors. You should look to rectify these first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web site with multiple languages can't use VB.NET classes in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412251/web-site-with-multiple-languages-cant-use-vb-net-classes-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 1):

VB and C# code can co-exist in the same App_Code. See [this page](http://virendradugar.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/using-c-and-vb-net-classes-together-in-the-app_code-folder/) to see how. Basically you just separate each into their own directory and modify your web.config.