# Can I used VB App_Code classes in my C# App_Code classes in asp.net web forms?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, app-code

The ASP.NET Web Forms site I'm working on is transitioning away from VB to C#, so we have many classes in VB but all new classes are supposed to be in C#.

The `App_Code` directory has a subdirectory, `App_Code/CSCode`, for C# code, and the main `App_Code` directory contains the VB classes.

I want to reference a VB class from `App_Code` in a C# class in `App_Code/CSCode`, but I get compilation errors saying it can't find the VB class definition.

```
The type or namespace name 'VBClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is it possible to reference a VB class in `App_Code` from a C# class in `App_code/CSCode`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put them in a separate project and reference the project or do you need to have the code in the same project?

Comment: It looks like you're using "ASP.NET Websites" - I strongly recommend moving to the "ASP.NET Web Application" project type instead.

Comment: Putting the code into a separate project or changing the project type would be pretty big changes, and I don't think my boss would go for it.

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9412251/256431). If it solves your problem, I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I settled on reimplementing the VB class I needed in C#, but thank you for the suggestions and explanations.